# React Router DOM 6 replace history with navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How can I replace this:

```
history.replace({
  ...location,
  search: ''
});
```

with navigate from `useNavigate` (React Router DOM 6).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`navigate(to, { replace: true }).`
If you need state,  `navigate(to, { state })`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let [, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

setSearchParams({});
```